# Scan available wifi networks in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios7, wifi

I want to know through my app that wifi is on or not and if the wifi is on then i want to list down all the available wifi networks that are available in the surroundings.How can i check through the app that wifi is on or not?And which framework should i use to list down all the available wifi networks?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the IPhone 5 uses the BCM4329 radio chipset which can enter promiscuous mode when jailbroken.. Using that it should be able to use the aircrack-ng suite for all your scanning needs.. I can't help you with operational install but this should be the basics

Comment: Thanks.. Actually i have office phone and i think they won't permit me to do this :P